# Standard In and Out for the process run using tcl shell

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, tcl

I am writing an Eclipse plugin for a debugger similar to GDB. This debugger is written in C and uses TCL library to process the commands. Debugger frontend creates and adds TCL extensions which are processed using TCL Shell. I am trying to run the debugger executable from my java code and read the standard in and out to communicate with the application. But my java process is not getting anything on both the pipes. If I change the executable to gdb, my logic works just fine.

I have never used Tcl before and not sure if Tcl shell has anything to do with blocking process in and out? Please provide your inputs or any possible pointers on this.

Comment: Good job on explaining what you are trying to do but please add more details, preferably some code, so that others can check out what you have done and maybe point out something because of which you are not getting intended behavior from your logic.

Comment: Pls. show a minimal, but working Java snippet of how you exactly call out to the system process hosting the `tclsh`.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem in this area relates to not flushing the output to the other process, and this can be an issue *both* ways. On the Java side, you must call the `flush()` method on the writer after you have written a complete message (often a whole line). On the Tcl side, you use `flush stdout` after writing a line, or you configure the standard output channel to automatically flush after each line is written:

```
fconfigure stdout -buffering line
```

With a binary protocol, you'd instead disable buffering entirely (`none` instead of `line`) and just ensure that messages where completely assembled before every write.